# Calculating $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}\arctan(n^{2}k)}{n^{\alpha}+k^{3/2}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I am studying for my exam in real analysis and I am having difficulties
with some of the material, I know that the following should be solved
by using the counting measure and LDCT, but I don't know how.

> For $\alpha>0,$ Calculate
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}\arctan(n^{2}k)}{n^{\alpha}+k^{3/2}}$$

I would greatly appreciate it if in the answers you can include all the details
about the theorems used (since there is a high importance for the
arguments for why we can do what we do in each step, and I don't understand
the material good enough to be able to understand that some step is
actually not trivial and uses some theorem)

Comment: By "arctg", do you by any chance mean "arctangent", which can be written either as "arctan", "atan", or "$\tan^{-1}$"? (someone has edited it to say that. Is it what you intended?)

Comment: @GlenO - Yes, this is what I mean. thanks for asking it to clarify, and sorry for the wrong spelling of the name of the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that for terms of serie $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k}\arctan(n^{2}k)}{n^{\alpha}+k^{3/2}}$ we have
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{(-1)^{k}\arctan(n^{2}k)}{n^{\alpha}+k^{3/2}}\right|
= 
&
\left| \frac{\arctan(n^{2}k)}{n^{\alpha}+k^{3/2}}\right|
\\
\leq
&
\left| \frac{2\pi}{n^{\alpha}+k^{3/2}}\right|
\\
=
&
\left| \frac{\pi}{\frac{n^{\alpha}+k^{3/2}}{2}}\right|
\\
\leq
&
\frac{\pi}{\sqrt[2\,]{n^{\alpha}\cdot k^{3/2}}}
\\
=
&
\frac{\pi}{n^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\cdot k^{3/4}}
\\
=
&
\frac{1}{n^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}\frac{\pi}{k^{3/4}}
\end{align}
Then 
$$
0\leq \left| \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k}\arctan(n^{2}k)}{n^{\alpha}+k^{3/2}}\right|\leq \sum_{k=1}^n\left|\frac{1}{n^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}\frac{\pi}{k^{3/4}}\right|
$$
By [Squeeze Theorem for Sequences](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Squeeze_Theorem/Sequences/Real_Numbers), $\sum_{k=1}^n\left|\frac{1}{n^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}\frac{\pi}{k^{3/4}}\right|\to 0$ (for all $\alpha>0$) implies $\left|\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k}\arctan(n^{2}k)}{n^{\alpha}+k^{3/2}}\right| \to 0$

Comment: Can you please explain the second inquality and the last line: what is the parameter that tends to infinity in the beginning and the "implies" part

Comment: @Belgi $|\arctan(x)|\leq \frac{\pi}{2}\leq 2\pi$. Remember of graphic of function $\arctan(x)$.

Comment: @Belgi, Sorry. The second inequality is aritimetic-geometric inequality: $\sqrt[2\,]{a\cdot b}\leq \frac{a+b}{2}$ implies $\frac{1}{\frac{a+b}{2}}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt[2\,]{a\cdot b}}$

Comment: Perhaps I'm deeply wrong, but $\sum^{n}_{k=1}\biggr|\frac{1}{n^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}\frac{\pi}{k^{3/4}}\biggr|=(\pi/n^{\alpha/2})\sum^{n}_{k=1}\biggr|\frac{1}{k^{3/4}}\biggr|$. Assuming, say, $\alpha=0.00001$, we have $\frac{\pi}{n^{\alpha/2}}\sum^{n}_{k=1}\biggr|\frac{1}{k^{3/4}}\biggr|\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Indeed, the series with respect ot $k$ has to be evaluated in full, independently on $n$. So, calling $N$ the upper limit, we first have to send $N\to\infty$ and *then* we can send $n\to\infty$. Unfortunately, when sending $N\to\infty$ we get a divergent series, so we cannot conclude anything.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a(n,k):=(-1)^k\frac{\arctan(n^2k)}{n^{\alpha}+k^{3/2}}$; then $|a(n,k)|\leqslant \frac{\pi}{2k^{3/2}}$ for each $n$, hence 
$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}a(n,k)\right|\leqslant \sum_{k=1}^N|a(n,k)|+\frac{\pi}2\sum_{k\geqslant N+1}k^{-3/2},$$
which gives that for each integer $N$, 
$$\limsup_{n\to +\infty}\left|\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}a(n,k)\right|\leqslant\sum_{k\geqslant N+1}k^{-3/2}.$$
Conclude (we actually used dominated convergence theorem).

Comment: Can you please explain how you got the line after "which gives that for" and where did you use LDCT ? 
This means that the sum is $0$, right ?

Comment: Taking the $\limsup$ on both sides, the first sum converges to $0$ because we considered _finitely_ many terms which converge to $0$. We took bound which doesn't depend on $n$.

Comment: @Davide Giraudo It was not to calculate the value of the serie?

Comment: @E.Costa It seems we just need the limit as $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: But the elements in the first sum seem to tend to $0$ when $k$ tends to infinity, not when $n$ does. I also still don't understand the use of LDCT...

Comment: $\alpha$ is positive, so I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo - Why do say that the elements in the sum tends to $0$ (as $n$ tends to infinity) ? they go to $\pi$ divided by $k^{3/2}$

Comment: @Belgi I don't think so... for each $k$, we have that $(-1)^{k}\frac{\arctan{n^{2}k}}{n^{\alpha}+k^{3/2}}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, because the numerator tends to $\pi/2$ for $k>0$ and in the denominator we have $k^{3/2}$, which does not change, and $n^\alpha$, which tends to $\infty$ for $\alpha>0$...